# NextJS static builds refers files to C://?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a NextJS project that I will export as a static site. I chose the framework due to the size the application will have and the ease with which routes are created and maintained in NextJS. I'm trying to export the static version of the site with `next build && next export -o stable-build`, which works fine. However, when I double-click my `index.html` file, the loaded content is not referenced properly. Oppening Chrome and Edge devtools I found the reason:

[image]

The file is trying to get all scripts from `file:///C:/_next/chunks/filename.js`. When I move everything into `C://` it works fine. How do I change `next export` for all files references to be relative to the build output folder? I went through NextJS documentation on static builds and found nothing to change this. Nor did I find any previous question or topic of discussion in the matter. This is my current `next.config.js file`, which is pretty basic, with nothing fancy in it:

```
const withOptimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');

module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
};

module.exports = withOptimizedImages({
    handleImages: ['jpeg', 'png', 'svg'],
});
```

If there's any other info that might be helpful to the question, please let me know.

Comment: You need to ["serve"](https://github.com/vercel/serve) the generated output, not just open the HTML files. The path are relative, they just are not present on your basepath. Assume you are on `protocol://foo/bar/`, then if you try to request `/bar` it will request `protocol://foo/baz` not `protocol://foo/bar/baz`. The same is happening in your case. Your page URL is something like `file:///C:/some/long/path/index.html`, then if you request anything like `/foo`, then your browser will try to fetch from the base, i.e., `file:///C:/foo`.

Comment: Next.js comes with a default server. After `npm run build` run another command `npm run start` to start the server. (Assuming you bootstrapped the app using create-next-app)

Comment: There is a complete discussion on this present in the official Next.js repository: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/2581